# c# mshtml on webbrowser winforms

Tags: c#, browser, mshtml

I need to intercept the textbox click on the DOM in webbrowser control in c#.
I searched a lot in the internet and I learned to use mshtml.dll.
Includes it in the project and this is my example:

```
mshtml.HTMLDocument doc;
        doc = (mshtml.HTMLDocument)webMain.Document;
        mshtml.HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event iEvent;
        iEvent = (mshtml.HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event)doc;
        iEvent.onclick += new mshtml.HTMLDocumentEvents2_onclickEventHandler(ClickEventHandler);
```

but when I try to write my code i've got this problem:

**Cannot convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument' to 'mshtml.HTMLDocument'
**

I think the problem is the webbrowser control class, but i don't know why.
Any ideas?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Use the HtmlDocument.DomDocument property, it exposes the native object.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but i found another way to achieve my final goal, disable explorer.exe